# create a hash from command line in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with data like below:

```
4  1
7  12
2  5
4  4
6  67
12  5
```

through command line i can split each and every line  into an array like below:

```
perl -F'\s+' -ane 'print $F[0]' file
```

thus will print all the first fields.
Now the above command transforms every line into an array.
in a similar way can this be done line creating a hash with keys as the first field and values for each key is the second field.?

Comment: If you use that sample input to build a hash, you will overwrite the key/value pair `4 => 1` with `4 => 4`, since hash keys are unique. Also, `-F'\s+'` is redundant, since that is the default autosplit value when using `-a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -ane '$X{$F[0]}=$F[1]}{print Dumper \%X' file
```

Comment: Wow an unknown benefactor optimised my code! Thanks.  This was a submission from my phone, so double thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e '%a = map { (split)[0,1] } <ARGV>;print Dumper \%a' dt.txt
```